# Is this PostGIS database design question better suited to the DBA site or the GIS site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I asked the following question on the GIS site:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328463/postgis-proper-way-to-model-object-that-follows-sections-of-another-objects-pa

Is that the best place for it, or is it better to have it on the DBA site? It feels like I might be getting a bit deep into database design for the GIS site, but also realize this site probably doesn't deal with GIS stuff all that often.

Should it stay on GIS or be moved to the DBA site?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should pick the site that you think makes the most sense for your question and target audience knowledgeability. If you think that the GIS folks are the most knowledgeable, you should start there. It certainly seems to be on-topic for them.

If they want to mark it as not-appropriate, then you could certainly ask that here for system design/organization. We may not say that all design questions are on-topic, but this looks like a fun problem and we usually like those.

Remember, almost all database design is highly subjective overall. There are many right-solutions.

I'll also say that Evan is correct, there is often a LOT of overlap on site intentions. It's possible, for example, to find overlap between diy.stackexchange.com and english.stackexchange.com, even when it doesn't seem likely. We just try to find the site that we think works best, and work with moderators if we need to change things.

Comment: You're more likely to get away with being totally reasonable on [dba.se].

Answer (score -3):

Most sites in StackExchange have overlapping subject matter. It's a mess. A useless mess. You'll never fix it. You'll just piss people off. We could very easily define the two sites to not-overlap for 99.9999% of the use cases, but it'll never happen.

You can find questions on database administration and SQL on StackOverflow. QED.

I [asked a question on GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/240104/revisions), and got burned by the mods. So I took all of my GIS questions over here. From my perspective, our moderators are far nicer and better informed. And, that's  how advanced users pick what sites they want to be members of.

BTW, I see you're a [valuable contributor of Ask Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/users/9308/azendale) That's cool, [I was too](https://askubuntu.com/users/29097/evan-carroll). [I've since moved to Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3285/evan-carroll), and let me tell you this ... Their moderators are about 10,000x - 15,000x more informed, fair, and reasonable. I highly suggest checking it out: all questions on Ubuntu are valid there too!